# WCF service very slow response on large loads

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service and when we make like 40 simulatenosly calls to the service and we start seeing a lot of timeous on the client. Please see attached picture of wcf trace log[image] , sorted by duration. The service and client are on same machine, using standard tcp binding.

Error we see are

1) The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.
2) System.IO.PipeException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
There was an error writing to the pipe: The pipe is being closed. (232, 0xe8).

Update on further testing...

Looks like this happens only when the service does some work , if I comment out the work I am doing in the service it takes same 1000 / in 3min requests with no problems.

The client has like 40 active connection to the server.

Even with a sample app , i see same errors. I have do following in server ..

```
public double Add(double n1, double n2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("this is a test");
    }
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

and do the following on the client

```
 Action<string> a = CallService5000TimesInLoop;

         for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
         {
             a.BeginInvoke("Url",null,null);
         }
```

Comment: please select a red line to get exception details

Comment: Don't have an answer to your timeout issue but unless there's a specific reason you're using `netTcpBinding`, try using either the regular `wsHttpBinding` or the newer `netHttpBinding` (if you're concerned with network bandwidth). Since HTTP is sessionless it can usually scale better under load than the connection-oriented TCP transport. Yes, HTTP relies on TCP under-the-covers but it does not attempt to maintain "connections" between clients the service which is one thing that can cause timeouts.

Comment: check if you are in buffered mode...